# Undefined variable: ... in ...on line 9

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a form that updates a datebase but it gives me two errors. Do you have any idea what it could be from?
The errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Points inD:\2013.1\xampp\htdocs\ranklist_get.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Skype in D:\2013.1\xampp\htdocs\ranklist_get.php on line 9

**welcome.html**

```
<body>
<form action="ranklist_get.php" method="get">
Skype: <input type="text" id="Skype"><br>
Points: <input type="number" id="Points"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ranklist_get.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points='".$Points."' WHERE Skype='".$Skype."'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Isn't that so easy already? You really don't have those variables declared anywhere and you are using them in your query. I don't see any value being assigned to `$Points` or `$Skype` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variables with the expected values before you use them in your query.

```
$Points=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["Points"]);
$Skype=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["Skype"]);
```

Also make sure to add the `name` attribute to your form fields. `name="Points"` and `name="Skype"`, otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

`GET` variables are stored in the global `$_GET` array (just like `POST` and `COOKIE`). You can either use them directly in your code like so `$_GET["Points"]` or store them in a variable.

Please note you should use the `name` property on each input to specify it's key in the array.

At the top of your code put:

```
$Points = $_GET["Points"];
$Skype = $_GET["Skype"];
```

Your form should be rewritten like so:

```
<form action="ranklist_get.php" method="get">
Skype: <input type="text" id="Skype" name="Skype"><br>
Points: <input type="number" id="Points" name="Points"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

You should also sanitize your MySQL query like so:

```
$query = mysqli->prepare($con, "UPDATE Persons SET Points=? WHERE Skype=?");
$query->bind_param('ss', $points, $skype);

$points = $_GET["Points"];
$skype = $_GET["Skype"];

$query->execute();
```

You can read more about prepared statements here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: That's almost 0 `preparation` of that query. It serves no purpose to prepare it with String interpolation.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Except for protection from SQL injection. It is up to the OP how they wish to bind parameters to it. This is purely as an example.

Comment: Never. That will never protect from SQL injection in any form. You have to prepare a query with placeholders and then bind the values to them, Not prepare a query with string interpolation. That's not the proper way to `prepare` a query. See this page that you linked, it has to be this format `SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?"` and then you bind a value to it.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I wasn't aware it wouldn't sanitise direct input... has been updated.

Comment: Now its perfect and safer, +1

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks for the info, I would of done that in production for the other benefits, it could of tripped me up though.

Answer (score 0):

make HTML as

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="ranklist_get.php" method="get">
Skype: <input type="text" id="Skype" name="Skype"><br>
Points: <input type="number" id="Points" name="Points"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ranklist_get.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if($_REQUEST['Submit']=='Submit'){
$Points=$_REQUEST['Points'];
$Skype=$_REQUEST['Skype'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points='".$Points."' WHERE Skype='".$Skype."'");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You have to get the values before you use it.